# Can not access member type from base-class when compiled using c++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, class-template

I have the following code which compiles successfully in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

```
template<class T, class ...Args>
class B 
{
public:
   using AbcData = int;
};

template<typename ...Args>
class D : public B<float, Args...>
{
public:
   AbcData m_abc;
};
```

But when compiled in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), it gives the following error.

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'AbcData'
```

What is wrong with the code and how to fix this?

Comment: This shouldn't have compiled on C++14 either.

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio 2017. It compiles in c++14.

Comment: Shouldn't have. It's always been ill-formed. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6ystv-).

Comment: It doesn't compile on MSVC with `/Za`, maybe they have an extension or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the base class `B` class depends upon the template parameters, even though derived class `D` here type alias `AbcData` inherited from the `B`, using simply `AbcData` in `D` class, is not enough.

You need to be explicit, from where you have it

```
template<typename ...Args>
class D : public B<float, Args...>
{
public:
    typename B<float, Args...>::AbcData m_abc; // --> like this
};
```

Comment: is this backward compatible with c++14 syntax?

Comment: @acegs Did you mean this: https://godbolt.org/z/qczVg7 ?

Comment: If `AbcData` is not ambiguous, you can use `D` itself instead of the base class `B<float, Args...>` to make the name dependent. That might be more straight-forward.

Comment: i'm using the `AbcData` multiple times so i used `using AbcData = B<float, Args...>::AbcData`. it's working now. is there better alternative that is shorter and less specifying too much redundant details? i also have other data types from base class not just `AbcData`.

Comment: @acegs Your line should not compile. It needs a `typename` before `B` and you can use `using typename B<float, Args...>::AbcData;` instead.

Comment: o yeah, i actually added `typename` in my actual code. i just typed manually the sample code in the comments. i forgot to add the `typename`.